# Query Wagtail Form Fields into Homepage

Tags: django, wagtail

I was wondering if it was possible to query the form fields from a abstract wagtail form into page model. I would like to put a wagtail form on my homepage(page) model, but don't really understand how you would accomplish this, if it is even possible.

Any feedback is appreciated

**home_page.html**

```
  ...
  <form action="{% pageurl page %}" method="POST">
          {% csrf_token %}
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12">

        {% if form.non_field_errors %}
            <div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert">
              {% for error in form.non_field_errors %}
                {{ error }}
              {% endfor %}
            </div>
              {% endif %}

        <h3>Contact Form</h3><br>
        </div>

       {% for item in page.formPage.all %}
        {% for field in form.visible_fields %}
        <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-12">
          <div class="form-group">
            {% render_field field class+="form-control" %}
          </div>
        </div>
        {% endfor %}
      {% endfor %}
        </div>
        <div class="pull-center">
          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-contact mt-3">Submit</button>
        </div>
    </form>
```

**models.py**

```
imports removed

class HomePage(Page):
    firstheader = RichTextField(blank=True)
    firstbody = RichTextField(blank=True)
    registerbuttonurl = models.CharField(blank=True, max_length=250)
    secondheader = RichTextField(blank=True)
    secondbody = RichTextField(blank=True)
    registerlink = RichTextField(blank=True)

    def Form(self):
        return FormPage.objects.all()

    content_panels = Page.content_panels + [

        FieldPanel('firstheader', classname="full"),
        FieldPanel('firstbody', classname="full"),
        FieldPanel('registerbuttonurl'),
        FieldPanel('secondheader', classname="full"),
        FieldPanel('secondbody', classname="full"),
        FieldPanel('registerlink', classname="full"),
        InlinePanel('gallery_images', label="Certified Distributor Logos"),
    ]



class FormField(AbstractFormField):
    page = ParentalKey('FormPage', on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='form_fields')


class FormPage(AbstractEmailForm):
    intro = RichTextField(blank=True)
    thank_you_text = RichTextField(blank=True)

    content_panels = AbstractEmailForm.content_panels + [
        FieldPanel('intro', classname="full"),
        InlinePanel('form_fields', label="Form fields"),
        FieldPanel('thank_you_text', classname="full"),
        MultiFieldPanel([
            FieldRowPanel([
                FieldPanel('from_address', classname="col6"),
                FieldPanel('to_address', classname="col6"),
            ]),
            FieldPanel('subject'),
        ], "Email"),
    ]


    thank_you_page = models.ForeignKey(
        'wagtailcore.Page',
        null=True,
        blank=True,
        on_delete=models.SET_NULL,
        related_name='+',
    )

    def render_landing_page(self, request, form_submission=None, *args, **kwargs):
        ...removed
```

Comment: What do you mean by "query the form fields into a page model"? Do you mean that you want to create a new page based on the content of the form fields? Do you want to perform a query on the previous form submissions and display the output on the page? Or do you just want to display the form on a page - in which case, can you tell us what's currently not working in your existing code?

Comment: I used "def Form(self): return FormPage.objects.all()" in the models.py to query in the formfields. I have a FormPage (AbstractEmailForm) and FormField(AbstractFormField) and I would like the visible form fields to appear on my HomePage(Page).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`return FormPage.objects.all()` won't work because the form fields are defined on one particular `FormPage` instance that you created in the admin, not on the `FormPage` class itself. You'll need something in your code to identify which `FormPage` you're referring to - I'd suggest giving it a unique slug (`contact-us` in this example) and retrieving it based on that.

```
class HomePage(Page):
    # ...
    def get_contact_form_page(self):
        return FormPage.objects.get(slug='contact-us')

    def get_contact_form(self):
        return self.get_contact_form_page().get_form()
```

Then, on your homepage template, you can access `page.get_contact_form` and render the resulting form in the same way as you would render it on the `FormPage`'s own template:

```
{% with page.get_contact_form as form %}
    <form action="{% pageurl page.get_contact_form_page %}" method="POST">
        {% csrf_token %}
        {% for field in form.visible_fields %}
            ...
        {% endfor %}
    </form>
{% endwith %}
```

Note that the form action is set up to post to the form page; putting `{% pageurl page %}` here will cause it to post back to the homepage, and the homepage doesn't know how to handle form submissions. Similarly, the code for displaying validation error messages can be left out of the homepage template - if the user submits an invalid form, they'll be dropped onto the contact-us page rather than the homepage.